# Does response from requests.get() use the same memory or allocates new memory each time in python?

Tags: python, memory, request, response, allocation

I use `dict_a['response'] = requests.get(given_url)` to get data from some website with given frequency using requests modular.
The returned response (`requests.get(given_url)`) is json object correponding to dictionaries, which is used later.

Does response from requests.get(given_url) use the same memory or allocates new memory each time in python?
If later is the case, then dict_a['response'] may be changed without notice.
I am afraid such situation happens and I use `dict_a['response'] = copy.deepcopy(requests.get(given_url))` each time.
It seems quite unnecessary so I choose to ask this question to make sure it's no need to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests.get is a method. Excluding unusual cases involving global variables (which requests does not use), method level variables are bound uniquely each time the method is called. Once the method returns, the returned object will be bound to whichever name you assign it to.

So if you do something like

```
dict[a] = requests.get(url1)
dict[b] = requests.get(url2)
```

You needn't worry that dict[a] will magically change to contain a response from url2. But of course

```
dict[a] = requests.get(url1)
dict[a] = requests.get(url2)
```

Will cause dict[a] to change.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionaries are not reused:

```
>>> url = 'http://google.com'
>>> requests.get(url) is requests.get(url)
False
```

Comment: That's true but `is` tests if they are the same object. `==` is only if they are considered equal (could be 2 objects in different memory locations). Regardless though `requests.get` doesn't return dictionaries?

Comment: @GP89:  Good point.  Editing answer.  (However, I was taking the `id` of the result, so it was equivalent to `is`.)

Comment: @GP89 In my case requests.get returns a json object corresponding to dictionary. Thanks for your notice and I will edit the question.

Comment: @Steven right, I commented before you made that edit though :P I expect that's all `is` is doing anyway.

Comment: Rumbalski, I learnt a new skill from your answer by your  'just do it' way. It's both simple and cool! Though I accept the second answer because it let me know the underlying reason, I own you a thank.